# Given $f: X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ continuous and $h:X\to Y$, $x\to$ {$f(x)$ if.., $g(x)$ if..}. In which points is $h$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Given continuous functions $f: X\to Y$ and $g:X \to Y$ with $(X,O_X)$ as one topology and $(Y,O_Y)$ as hausdorff topology. Also $A\subseteq X$ and  $h:X \to Y$,
where $h(x) = f(x) $ for $ x\in A$ and $h(x) = g(x) $ for $ x\in X/A $

In which points $x \in X$ is $h$ continuous?

Definition of continuity: $f$ is continuous in point $x$, if for every neighborhood $U$ of $f(x)$, $f^{-1} (U)$ is also a neighborhood of $x$ holds.

To be honest, I don't even know, what exactly I'm supposed to do. I have started with how $h^{-1}$(x) has to look like, but I'm clueless with those given conditions..

Any ideas of how $h^{-1}$(x) has to look like and what in general I should show?

Comment: MathJax works in the title section too, don't you know?

Comment: Also, use `$\to$` for $\to$.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give an answer with this generality. Consider the constant functions $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=1$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$.

If $A=\mathbb{Q}$, then the function $h$ is nowhere continuous.

Take instead as domain of $f$ and $g$ the set $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ and $A=(0,1)$. Then the function $h$ is everywhere continuous.

What you can safely state is that $h$ is continuous over the interior of $A$ and the interior of $X\setminus A$. But anything can happen at the boundary of $A$. In the second example above, the boundary is empty. But you can use
$$
f(x)=x,\qquad g(x)=-x
$$
over the reals and $A=(0,\infty)$. The function $h$ is everywhere continuous. If you change $g$ to $g(x)=1-x$, then the resulting function $h$ is not continuous at the boundary of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for giving some examples, from where we can assume/see that $h$ is definitely continuous over the interior of $A$ and of $X/A$! However, I still don't have an idea of how to show that in generality..

Comment: @Mathpiano If $x$ is in the interior of $A$, then $h$ coincides with $f$ in a full neighborhood of $x$.